# Creating instance of codependant classes C++11

Tags: c++, class, c++11

Why cant I create a instance of the class Bor in Consumer? Look at the following reduced example.

```cpp
##main.cpp
#include "Consumer.hpp"
#include "Bor.hpp"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Bor bor;
    return 0;
}
```

This here is the consumer:

```
##consumer.cpp

#include "Consumer.hpp"
#include "Bor.hpp"
Consumer::Consumer(Bor& bor) :
bor(bor) {}
void Consumer::startConsumeLoop() {}
```

The consumers header:

```
##consumer.hpp

#ifndef CONSUMER
#define CONSUMER
#include "Bor.hpp"
class Consumer{
 public:
    Consumer(Bor& bor);
    void startConsumeLoop();
 private:
    Bor& bor;
};
#endif
```

This is the Bor:

```
##Bor.cpp

#include "Bor.hpp"
#include "Consumer.hpp"
Bor::Bor(){}
```

The bor header:

```
##Bor.hpp

#ifndef BOR
#define BOR
#include "Consumer.hpp"
class Bor{
 public:
    Bor();
};
#endif
```

Here is the command i run to compile:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 Consumer.cpp Main.cpp Bor.cpp
```

and the error:

```
./Consumer.hpp:6:11: error: unknown type name 'Bor'
        Consumer(Bor& bor);
./Consumer.hpp:8:2: error: unknown type name 'Bor'
        Bor& bor;
```

Comment: Circular include files.  Get rid of `#include "Consumer.hpp" in `Bor.hpp`, since nothing in `Bor.hpp` depends on consumer.hpp.

Answer (score 3):

- Bor.hpp should not have `#include "Consumer.hpp"`.
- consumer.hpp may just have forward declaration of class `Bor` instead of include.